# When i try to enter subdomain i'm redirected to main domain

Tags: redirect, subdomains, domain, dns

I have wordpress site on my server connected to domain.pl and i also have my own html site connected to subdomain.domain.pl but every time i try to enter subdomain.domain.pl it redirects me to domain.pl

**Update**

this is my wordpress site .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

this is my domain.pl virtualhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName geoplay.pl
    ServerAlias www.geoplay.pl 
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/geoplay.pl
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.pl
    ServerName geoplay.pl
    ServerAlias www.geoplay.pl
    DocumentRoot /var/www/geoplay.pl
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/cloudflare/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/cloudflare/key.key
</VirtualHost>
```

and this is my subdomain.domain.pl virtualhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mapa.geoplay.pl
    ServerAlias www.mapa.geoplay.pl
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost.pl
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mapa.geoplay.pl
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.pl
    ServerName mapa.geoplay.pl
    ServerAlias www.mapa.geoplay.pl
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mapa.geoplay.pl
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/cloudflare/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/cloudflare/key.key
</VirtualHost>
```

---

this is my wordpress site .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

this is my domain.pl virtualhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName geoplay.pl
    ServerAlias www.geoplay.pl 
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/geoplay.pl
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.pl
    ServerName geoplay.pl
    ServerAlias www.geoplay.pl
    DocumentRoot /var/www/geoplay.pl
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/cloudflare/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/cloudflare/key.key
</VirtualHost>
```

and this is my subdomain.domain.pl virtualhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mapa.geoplay.pl
    ServerAlias www.mapa.geoplay.pl
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost.pl
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mapa.geoplay.pl
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.pl
    ServerName mapa.geoplay.pl
    ServerAlias www.mapa.geoplay.pl
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mapa.geoplay.pl
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/cloudflare/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/cloudflare/key.key
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Does your subdomain point to a subdirectory of your domain.pl? Please provide the content of htaccess files you use.

Comment: Please don't post extended information about your question as an answer; instead, [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/407709/edit) to include the information. I've updated your question with the server information you provided.